# Override RegisterController on Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

After seeing the vendor, LoginController and RegisterController controls the Login and Register in laravel backpack. So by default, in config.base.setup_auth_routes is `true`, I would like to know how to override these controller.

What I've tried so far, adding routes of 'register' to my RegisterController@method_name, so that it avoids the vendor RegisterController. But when I try to run it never reads my local RegisterController. Because apart from users table, I have accounts table which I put the account of the corresponding user account after registration. So after user creation in RegisterController, I want also to run an eloquent to create account of that registered user.

How can I achieve this. It's never a good option to manually edit the vendor files. Modifying local RegisterController and LoginController doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add routes to routes/web.php only then it's gonna pick your controller. You can check all your routes 'php artisan route:list' and find out /register route is pointing to backpack's register.

Add a route to web.php and point to your controller as below:

Route::post('register', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('register')

Check this too -> https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/base-about#authentication

I have tested it and it's working fine.